# Plotly HTML chart creating runtime error when deployed in netlify using Hugo

Tags: plotly, netlify, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm using Hugo [Academic theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/academic/) to build a personal blog and deploy it on netlify.
Everything was going fine, until i wrote a post including plotly charts made with python.

I exported the charts as HTML and created a shortcode named plotly-chart.html:

```
{{ $r := resources.Get (printf "plotly/%s.html" ($.Get 0)) }}
{{ $r.Content | safeHTML }}
```

to be called in my markdown posts with

```
{{< plotly-chart CHART_NAME_HERE >}}
```

Running on local was fine, and the charts where fast simple and cool. But when deployed to netlify im getting runtime error to build.

```
3:50:35 PM: Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime
```

I tested a post with only one chart, it worked fine, but when I use more of then the site simply does not get deployed, and they are not heavy stuff.

Is this a theme problem? There is other way to implement plotly charts?

Comment: Can you also paste in the error you're getting, please?

Comment: just added 3:50:35 PM: Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the charts were too heavy for netlify, but too light for a local machine. Everything worked when i used the official CDN as described in [this post](https://matteoguzzo.com/blog/embed-html-graphs-plotly/)